# How to pull distinct counts from two different tables at once at align rows

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I have two separate tables: `emr` and `treatment`. Each table has a `userID` column and a `provider` column. Currently, I'm doing a simple pull to count the number of distinct `userID`s that appear in the `emr` table like this:

```
SELECT distinct vender, count (distinct userID) AS EMR_Patients
from emr
group by 1
```

This gets me the following output:

```
vender | EMR_Patients
+++++++++++++++++++++
a        10,000
b         5,000
c        37,500
```

However, I want to include the number of `userID`s that also appear in the `treatment` table so I can see how many `userID`'s that have an emr record and also have a treatment of interest. The output I'm trying to get is:

```
vender | EMR_Patients| Treatment_Patients
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
a        10,000         4,000
b         5,000         3,000
c        37,500         9,000
```

I tried using a union:

```
SELECT distinct vender, count (distinct userID) AS EMR_Patients
    FROM emr
    GROUP BY 1
UNION ALL
(SELECT distinct vender, count (distinct userID) AS Treatment_Patients
    FROM treatment
    GROUP BY 1)
```

But this doesn't work correctly. Is there a way to do this as a union, or should I left join the two tables together beforehand? Or maybe there's a cleaner way than either of these options?

Answer (score 0):

Use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT e.vendor, e.EMR_Patients, t.Treatment_Patients
FROM (SELECT vendor, count(distinct userID) AS EMR_Patients
      FROM emr
      GROUP BY 1
     ) e
     (SELECT vendor, count(distinct userID) AS Treatment_Patients
      FROM treatment
      GROUP BY 1
     ) t
     ON e.vendor = t.vendor;
```

(I adjusted the spelling of "vendor".)

This will only include vendors in both tables.  If you want vendors that are missing from one of the tables, you need an outer join of some sort.  Your question is not clear on that.